# ft2build.h: No such file or directory на Linux Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora

I'm trying to compile an application via Cmake on Fedor Linux and I get this error

```
fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
   35 | #include <ft2build.h>
```

It is worth noting that freetype-devel is already installed in the system

Comment: "libfreetype2" : `/usr/include/freetype2/ft2build.h` was a header in `freetype-devel` till Fedora 37 .... https://github.com/servo/libfreetype2/blob/master/freetype2/include/ft2build.h **,,,, ,,,,** https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/37/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/f/freetype-devel-2.12.1-3.fc37.x86_64.rpm

Comment: E.g. Fedora 39 has `freetype-devel-2.13.1` . The file `ft2build.h` is still included in other rpm based OS, but omitted in Fedora 38 - 39. ...... https://de.freedif.org/savannah/freetype/freetype-2.13.2.tar.xz ........ So I would just include the file in the application or `/usr/include/freetype2/`